# Total Footer in Grid View not working

Tags: html, asp.net, gridview

when am trying to display total in footer it's not display .The grid view appear but without the footer I don't know what I miss but I know that there is no errors but the footer not display

my html :

```
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="debit">
            <ItemTemplate>

                 <asp:Label  ID="lblDebAmount" runat="server" Text='<%# (Eval("v_flag").ToString() =="d" ) ? string.Format("{0:0.000}",float.Parse(Eval("v_amount").ToString())): "0.000" %>'></asp:Label>
                  </ItemTemplate>
                  <FooterTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="totallblDebAmount" runat="server" />
     </FooterTemplate>       

        </asp:TemplateField>
      </Columns>
                             <FooterStyle BackColor="#336699" Font-    
          Bold="True" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Left" />
  <HeaderStyle BackColor="#336699" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White"    
   HorizontalAlign="Left" />
```

my code :

```
   protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    decimal totalPrice = 0;



    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        Label lblDebAmount = (Label)e.Row.FindControl("lblDebAmount");


        decimal debtotal = Decimal.Parse(lblDebAmount.Text);


        totalPrice += debtotal;



    } 

    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Footer)
    {
        Label totallblCAmount = (Label)e.Row.FindControl("totallblCAmount");


        totallblCAmount.Text = totalPrice.ToString();



    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try to modify

```
Label totallblCAmount = (Label)e.Row.FindControl("totallblCAmount");
```

to be

```
Label totallblCAmount = (Label)e.Row.FindControl("totallblDebAmount");
```